# how to set position of placeholder in mat-input

Tags: angular, css, angular-material, angular-material-5

I'm changing some styles in my mat-input. I got all of them but the position of the placeholder inside the input.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput type="email" name="email" [required]="true" placeholder="email" class="my-class"/>
</mat-form-field>

.my-class {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This works fine when there is an email inside the input, but when it's empty the placeholder "email" moves inside the input and it's on the top corner.

[image: good positoin]
[image: bad positoin]

By checking css, I discover than a class is added and deleted in mat-form-field, it's "mat-form-field-sould-float", my selector will be something like:

```
mat-form-field:not(.mat-form-field-should-float) .mat-input-placeholder
```

but I'm not able to make it work.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the view encapsulation, you won't be able to change the CSS of your input in your component's style sheet.

You will have to change `style.scss` at the root of your project. You can use the same selector :

```
mat-form-field:not(.mat-form-field-should-float) .mat-input-placeholder {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```